# how to overlap more graphs in r

Tags: r, graph

I want to to overlap 4 different graphs overlaying in one single graph.

Below is the code i have wrote for each graphs

```
years = 2010:2019

##1st graph - Rapporto Valore della Produzione Sud-Centro
plot.valProd.sud.centro = plot(years,c(rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd10,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd11,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd12,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd13,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd14,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd15,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd16,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd17,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd18,
rapp.valProd.sud.centro$ValProd19),
xlab = "Anni",ylab="Valore Produzione",type = "b",col="red",main="Sud vs Centro")


##2nd graph -Rapporto Capitale Sud-Centro
plot.immob.sud.centro = plot(years,c(rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob10,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob11,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob12,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob13,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob14,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob15,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob16,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob17,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob18,
rapp.immob.sud.centro$Immob19),
xlab = "Anni",ylab="Capitale",type = "b",col="black",main="Sud vs Centro")


##3rd graph - Rapporto Lavoro Sud-Centro
plot.lavoro.sud.centro = plot(years,c(rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti10,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti11,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti12,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti13,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti14,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti15,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti16,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti17,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti18,
rapp.lavoro.sud.centro$Dipendenti19),
xlab = "Anni",ylab="Lavoro",type = "b",col="green",main="Sud vs Centro")


##4th graph - Rapporto Produttività (A) Sud-Centro 
plot.produt.sud.centro = plot(years,c(rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività10,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività11,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività12,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività13,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività14,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività15,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività16,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività17,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività18,
rapp.produt.sud.centro$Produttività19),
xlab = "Anni",ylab="Produttività (A)",type = "b",col="blue",main="Sud vs Centro")
```

This is the combined format of four graphs:

[image]

So, I want to know that how can I overlap all four graphs in one graph?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see your data (which is clearly not in a helpful format!).  Also, please explore the value of using the spacebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  year = seq(2010, 2015, 1),
  value = c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.8)
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  year = seq(2010, 2015, 1),
  value = c(0.5,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9)
)

df_3 <- data.frame(
  year = seq(2010, 2015, 1),
  value = c(0.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.9,0.6)
)

df_4 <- data.frame(
  year = seq(2010, 2015, 1),
  value = c(0.1,0.5,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.7)
)

p1 <- ggplot(df_1, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line()

p2 <- ggplot(df_2, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line()

p3 <- ggplot(df_3, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line()

p4 <- ggplot(df_4, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line()


ggplot(df_1, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line(color = "pink") +
  geom_line(data = df_2, color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = df_3, color = "green") +
  geom_line(data = df_4, color = "blue")
```

[image]